# SQLite does not multiply columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a following sql statement in SQLite:

```
SELECT
...
CASE WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 10000 THEN 15
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 3000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 9999 THEN 10
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 1000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 2999 THEN 7.5
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 100 AND facebook_post_audience <= 999 THEN 5
ELSE 0 END 'Fb reward category',
facebook_post_number 'No. of FB posts/shares',
'Fb reward category' * facebook_post_number 'FB reward',
...
FROM table;
```

'FB reward' is supposed to show multiples of the previously defined columns but it shows only zeroes no matter what numbers are in those columns. Moreover, typeof('Fb reward category') says 'text' although there are only numbers there. Have I drunken too much coffee today or am I missing anything here?

Comment: You can't use an alias (`'Fb reward category'`) in an expression, if you do its just a string - it does not refer back to the actual computed values. What you actually have is `'a non numeric string' * number` which is always `0`.  You need to repeat the `CASE` or use a sub-query.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that clarifies the issue. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole case statement into the multiplication spot:

```
SELECT
...
CASE WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 10000 THEN 15
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 3000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 9999 THEN 10
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 1000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 2999 THEN 7.5
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 100 AND facebook_post_audience <= 999 THEN 5
ELSE 0 END 'Fb reward category',
facebook_post_number 'No. of FB posts/shares',
CASE WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 10000 THEN 15
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 3000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 9999 THEN 10
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 1000 AND facebook_post_audience <= 2999 THEN 7.5
WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 100 AND facebook_post_audience <= 999 THEN 5
ELSE 0 END * facebook_post_number 'FB reward',
...
FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, now it works as supposed. Moreover, the first CASE could be left out as its only role was to generate relevant numbers for multiplying which is now done by your addition.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery or CTE.  And, while you are at it, give your column aliases reasonable names that don't need to be escaped:

```
SELECT ...,
       facebook_post_number,
       fb_reward_category* facebook_post_number as rb_reward,
       ...
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (CASE WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 10000 THEN 15
                   WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 3000 THEN 10
                   WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 1000 THEN 7.5
                   WHEN facebook_post_audience >= 100 THEN 5
                   ELSE 0
              END) as FB_reward_category 
      FROM table t
     ) t
```

I also simplified the `case` expression so it is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your code is more straightforward then that which I begun with. Will use it.